# ListView item have a linearlayout , linearlayout addView then getview be called,and ImageView flashed.what can i do for image not to flash

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

user is a bean,head is an imageView,ll is a layout param. when click add button the follow code be called. then adapter call getview and every thing in this item will be refresh but data have no changed. so imageView inside of item,must be flashed.how wo fix it?

```
    if (mUsers==null) {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<ThreadUser>();
    }
    mUsers.add(0, user);
    ll_Collect.addView(head,0,ll);
    if (mUsers.size()>7) {
        mUsers.remove(mUsers.size()-1);
        ll_Collect.removeViewAt(ll_Collect.getChildCount()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call this function

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: the result i want is imageView does not blink

Comment: for that you should run a thread inside getview method and manage imagview visiblity